# Query all contacts in account related to opportunity

Tags: soql, opportunity, account, contact

I am trying to pull a list of all contacts in accounts with certain opportunities.  My initial query looks like this:

```
Select Id, Name , Account.id
From Opportunity 
WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('1A,'1B')
```

This identifies a few hundred opportunities, now what I can't figure out is how to relate this back to the associated Account to list all of the contacts in those Accounts.  There should be a relation that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOQL query will be like this, you need to join based on `AccountId`, which is known as Left Inner join query

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId IN 
    (SELECT AccountId 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('1A','1B'))
```

For more information, refer [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)

Comment: You rock!  Thanks, this example is a huge help and is exactly what I needed.